# No type arguments expected for fun findViewById(p0: Int): View

Tags: android, kotlin

i tried to declare an imageView on Kotlin like this :

```
view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabImage)).setImageResource(selector)
```

but i get always this error,

```
Error:(30, 27) No type arguments expected for fun findViewById(p0: Int): View!
```

Could someone help PLZ ?
Thx

Comment: Use   val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabImage) and then 
            imageView.setImageResource(selector)

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.tabImage) as ImageView
imageView.setImageResource(selector)
```

Comment: @taoufik-Storm, That doesn't seem to match the error in the question. Those look like different `findViewById` definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one or more dependencies replace the SDK to older? Please check your dependencies and repositories.

I was the same problem with `org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:0.10.0-beta-2` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` but with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` work fine.

I solve it by upgrade to `org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:0.10.4`. Now it works with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabImage)  
imageView.setImageResource(selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private var aImageView : ImageView? = null
aImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview) as ImageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val tabimage = findViewById(R.id.tabImage) as ImageView
tabimage.setImageResource(selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using safe casting '?' solved it.

```
private var imageView: ImageView? = null
```

.
.
.

```
   imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.tabImage)  as? ImageView
   imageView.setImageResource(selector)
```